# Get Date from HTML Element and compare it to Today's Date JS

Tags: javascript, html, date, compare, element

I have only just started coding in javascript so I have not got everything learned down pat.

I would like to reference a date in an element on an HTML page and use javascript to alert the user that the Date is in the past.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var EndDate = document.getElementById("Close");
document.getElementById("AuctionDate").innerHTML = 
Date.parse(EndDate.innerHTML);
var TodaysDate = Date.parse(Date());
document.getElementById("TodaysDate").innerHTML = TodaysDate;
if (EndDate < TodaysDate) {
    alert("Closed");
    } else { 
    alert("Open");
}
```

```html
<span id="Close">27 September 2017</span>
<p id="AuctionDate"></p>
<p id="TodaysDate"></p>
```

I've converted today's date into a number and shown it to see if it worked.
I can't seem to figure out how to compare them properly as I could not find out how to make the EndDate parse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you currently have it, you're grabbing the `.innerHTML` from `Close`, and assigning that straight to `EndDate`. This value (`27 September 2017`) is then compared against the current timestamp (`1506645355000`). Strings are compared **[lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)**, so JavaScript thinks that the string of `27 September 2017` is 'larger' than the integer `1506645355000`.

What you need to do is move your `Date.parse()` to the first line, wrapping your `Date.parse()` in the variable assignment itself, so that your variable `EndDate` ends up with the parsed date.

Then, if required, you can output this back to the page by setting the target `.innerHTML` of `AuctionDate` to the variable `EndDate` directly:

```js
var EndDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("Close").innerHTML);
console.log("EndDate's value is: " + EndDate) // returns a parsed date
document.getElementById("AuctionDate").innerHTML = EndDate;
var TodaysDate = Date.parse(Date());
document.getElementById("TodaysDate").innerHTML = TodaysDate;
if (EndDate < TodaysDate) {
  alert("Closed");
} else {
  alert("Open");
}
```

```html
<span id="Close">27 September 2017</span>
<p id="AuctionDate"></p>
<p id="TodaysDate"></p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (new Date('27 September 2017') < new Date('28 September 2017')) {
  console.log('still open')
}

// where
// 27 September 2017 is dateToday
// 28 September 2017 is dateCloses

var today = document.getElementById("TodaysDate").innerHTML
var dateToday = new Date(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original `var EndDate = document.getElementById("Close");` is just getting the DOM *element* where you have put your date.
So your subsequent comparison `if (EndDate < TodaysDate)` is comparing a *DOM Element* `<` *Date Object*

You can get the date from your `Close` html element by selecting the element and then getting the text within it:
`var dateString = document.getElementById('Close').innerText`

Since you want to deal with Date objects, you can then parse it:
`var EndDate = Date.parse(dateString)`

At this point you can compare the two Date objects.

Note also, there is no point parsing a Date object:
`var TodaysDate = Date.parse(Date());`
You can simply do
`var TodaysDate = new Date();`

I know they don't *look* the same, but you really want to deal with `Date` objects throughout.

---

Side note: you should usually use `.innerText` rather than `.innerHTML`
Take this example -- say that instead of this
`<span id="Close">27 Septermber 2017</span>`
you had a more complex structure:
`<span id="Close"><span class="day">27</span> <span class="month">September</span> <span class="year">2017</span></span>`

In this case, close.innerHtml would give you that whole mess
`<span id="Close"><span class="day">27</span> <span class="month">September</span> <span class="year">2017</span></span>`

but close.innerText would give just `27 September 2017`

Whether you want innerText or innerHTML depends on what you're actually do with what you've got; know the difference and know which you want.